# write and read Graph, multiGraph, Digraph, MultiDigraph

Tags: graph, networkx, digraphs, osmnx

Read and Write, Multigraph, MultiDiGraph ?

I'm working with networkx and osmnx, And I wanted to know if there is any way to write and read a Multigraph and MultiDigraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) explains how to [save graphs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.save_graphml) to disk and then [reload them](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.load_graphml) again later.

Comment: I've tested this, none of  ox.save_graphml(graph, filename='graph.graphml', folder=None, gephi=False)
 ox.save_graph_shapefile(graph, filename='mynetwork_shapefile') works. Any idea why? Graph is generated correctly and then I can save GeoDataFrame using to_file method.